# Running Remote Desktop SERVER on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop-services

Is it possible to obtain Remote Desktop Services to enable W7 Pro to host multiple remote desktop sessions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am afraid not, but you can use GoGlobal from Graphon to achieve that on XP and Windows 7 i guess.

Comment: it's through a commercial solution, but it works, he will have many users accessing desktop or applications remotely on a Windows 7 workstation

Answer (score 4):

No, this is by design.

There are some "patches" around which can actually do this, but it's of course totally unsupported, and it also violates the EULA.